# Deserialize complex JSON object using c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I know how to deserialize basic Json object. I am having a problem with nested objects; for example, here is an example json i want to deserialize.

```
{
    "data": {
        "A": {
            "id": 24,
            "key": "key",
            "name": "name",
            "title": "title"
        },
        "B": {
            "id": 37,
            "key": "key",
            "name": "name",
            "title": "title"
        },
        "C": {
            "id": 18,
            "key": "key",
            "name": "name",
            "title": "title"
        },
        "D": {
            "id": 110,
            "key": "key",
            "name": "name",
            "title": "title"
        }
      },
    "type": "type",
    "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

Now `"data"` has an unknown number of objects, could be 100 could be 1000 or could be just 1 and all of them with different name. My ultimate goal is to get the information of each object inside data.

I tried basic json but didn't work at all.

Anyways, this is what I have tried...

I made class called data

```
public class data
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}
```

then I made another class called test

```
public class test
{
    /*
    I have also tried this, which works but then I don't know what to do with it and how to deserialize the information of it.
    //public Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer data { get; set; }
    */
    public List<List<data>> data { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
}
```

and in my driver application I did this

```
 string downloadedData = w.DownloadString(link);
 test t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<test>(downloadedData);
```

But this didn't work as I expected to.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In the test class how about public Dictionary<string, data> data. Instead of List<List<data>>

Comment: You can generate JSON-classes from JSON code from within visual studio. Select your JSON code, copy it to the clipboard, then go to `EDIT -> PASTE SPECIAL -> JSON TO CLASSES`. Then you can use the generated classes for deserialization.

Comment: @Michael while that's a very good tip it will not work for this example.

Comment: @SamMarion Thank you! I got it to work using Dictionary.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the tip, I took a look into it as well, its great but like SamMarion said, it's not what I was looking for in this example, but thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for a dictionary.

Use this as your class definition:

```
public class Rootobject
    {
        public Dictionary<string, DataObject> data { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string version { get; set; }
    }
    public class DataObject
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string key { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
    }
```

And this demonstrates that reading your object works:

```
var vals = @"{

""data"": {
    ""A"": {
        ""id"": 24,
        ""key"": ""key"",
        ""name"": ""name"",
        ""title"": ""title""
    },
    ""B"": {
        ""id"": 37,
        ""key"": ""key"",
        ""name"": ""name"",
        ""title"": ""title""
    },
    ""C"": {
        ""id"": 18,
        ""key"": ""key"",
        ""name"": ""name"",
        ""title"": ""title""
    },
    ""D"": {
        ""id"": 110,
        ""key"": ""key"",
        ""name"": ""name"",
        ""title"": ""title""
    }
  },
""type"": ""type"",
""version"": ""1.0.0""
}";
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(vals);
```