# Reading dynamic json types in c#

Tags: c#, json

You can find the whole json file [here](https://pastebin.com/4XFuQ7H1).

A small section of it:

```
{
   "35891":[
      {
         "itemId":5021,
         "minAmount":1,
         "maxAmount":1000,
         "rate":100,
         "rarity":"ALWAYS",
         "announce":false
      },
      {
         "itemId":22374,
         "minAmount":1,
         "maxAmount":1,
         "rate":0.033,
         "rarity":"RARE",
         "announce":true
      },
      {
         "itemId":22375,
         "minAmount":1,
         "maxAmount":1,
         "rate":0.033,
         "rarity":"RARE",
         "announce":true
      },
      {
         "itemId":22376,
         "minAmount":1,
         "maxAmount":1,
         "rate":0.033,
         "rarity":"RARE",
         "announce":true
      },
      {
         "itemId":20510,
         "minAmount":1,
         "maxAmount":1,
         "rate":0.0066,
         "rarity":"RARE",
         "announce":true
      }
   ],
   "25084":[
      {
         "itemId":22729,
         "minAmount":1,
         "maxAmount":1,
         "rate":0.0042,
         "rarity":"RARE",
         "announce":true
      },
      {
         "itemId":22730,
         "minAmount":1,
         "maxAmount":1,
         "rate":0.0042,
         "rarity":"RARE",
         "announce":true
      },
      {
         "itemId":22731,
         "minAmount":1,
         "maxAmount":1,
         "rate":0.0042,
         "rarity":"RARE",
         "announce":true
      },
      {
         "itemId":22732,
         "minAmount":1,
         "maxAmount":1,
         "rate":0.0042,
         "rarity":"RARE",
         "announce":true
      }
   ]
}
```

I mainly want to be able to get every "item" out of it. A example of an item is "35891" and I want to be able to get the data for "35891".

I've tried the following:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.RegisterConverters(new[] { new DynamicJsonConverter() });

dynamic obj = serializer.Deserialize(readText, typeof(object));
```

And also using the normal `Json.Deserialize`

After reading the data I also want to be able to write it (serialize).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize complex JSON object using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47187996/deserialize-complex-json-object-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Hi, So question must be self containt. May you [edit] a part of that json into your question directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [NewtonSoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/):

```
public class Data
{
    public int itemId { get; set; }
    public int minAmount { get; set; }
    public int maxAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal rate { get; set; }
    public string rarity { get; set; }
    public bool announce { get; set; }
}

...

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Data[]>>("your json here");
```

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Could not convert string to integer: ALWAYS. Path '35891[0].rarity', line 8, position 24.'

Comment: @Kyle fixed Data class

Comment: This worked but I can't var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Data[]>>(readText);
            MessageBox.Show((result[0]).ToString());

Comment: @Kyle It's a dictionary so use it as dictionary.

Comment: How do I foreach/index trough it? @mtkachenko

Comment: How to access dictionary value from [msdn exemple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8#examples)

Comment: @Kyle `Dictionary` is a unordered type. So no index available. But you can use `foreach` to iterate over the `Dictionary`. You will get a `KeyValuePair` in each iteartion.

Comment: @Kyle read this tutorial https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-dictionary

Comment: @mtkachenko Now that I can loop trough

Comment: string readText = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\kyllian.lissens\Downloads\npc_drops.json");
            int i = 0;
            BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)this.dataGridView1.DataSource;

            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Data[]>>(readText);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Data[]> entry in result)
            {

                Data[] dat = (Data[])entry.Value;
                string npc = entry.Key;
                MessageBox.Show("NPC: " + npc + "\n" + dat[i]);



                
            }

Comment: How do I get each drop ( the dat[] ) from one key

Comment: nvm figured it out